# Rotating a 3D view with mouse movements - with a fixed camera

Tags: java, 3d, trigonometry, java-3d, coordinate-transformation

**The background**
https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/force-atlas-3d/

**The problem**
- I have a network of nodes represented in (x,y,z) coordinates on a screen.
- The position of the mouse pointer is represented with (x,y) coordinates on screen (well, just as normal).

=> I'd like to use dragging movements from the mouse (variations in x and y) to rotate the view of the network of nodes.

- dragging the mouse to the left would cause a rotation of the nodes around the vertical axis, to the left ("rotation" is not operationally defined here I know, but I hope you visualize what I mean).
- dragging the mouse to the bottom of the screen would cause a rotation of the nodes around the horizontal axis, in the direction of the viewer.

As I see it I need a method taking variations in mouse coordinates as input, and returning the correspondong variations of their coordinates for each node.

**Notes**
- no camera movement here.
- the solution is developed in Java - maybe that some libraries like Java3D are relevant here?

Any help would be appreciated - and acknowledged in the Gephi plugin I'm building! Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [orbit behavior](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/com/sun/j3d/utils/behaviors/vp/OrbitBehavior.html) class

```
OrbitBehavior orbit = new OrbitBehavior(canvas, OrbitBehavior.REVERSE_ROTATE);
orbit.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
universe.getViewingPlatform().setViewPlatformBehavior(orbit);
```

It rotates the view in all directions. you can however restrict the rotation to the left and right directions(depending on the direction of the mouse) by setting the Y rotation movement multiplier to 0 as follows:

```
orbit.setRotXFactor(2);//or any other value
orbit.setRotYFactor(0);
```